# Can't open USB floppy drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, floppy

I have bought USB Floppy Drive but unable to use it.

Windows says

[image]

The reason why I think it may be programmatic reason, is that antivirus can test this disk and report number of files tested.

**UPDATE**

There are multiple following errors in Windows log:

> The description for Event ID 7 from source sfloppy cannot be found.
>   Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your
>   local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or
>   repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> \Device\Floppy0

Comment: How many different disks have you tried?  What happens if you try to format one of them before using it?

Comment: Its weird the AV can read the disc and scan the files...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I tried several and found similar behavior, including this message, explorer freezing and so on.

Comment: Is this a new drive or a second-hand one?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me every time. Plug your drive in to the USB port before you boot. Put a disk in if you like but not required and you run the risk ruining the data if any. The drive will setup at boot. After booting insert the disk and open a command prompt and just type and enter A:. It will go to the A: drive and you can list the directory. Click on MY PC in the file manager and the drive will be there.

Also if you want to use a Windows 10 or 11 floppy disk on a dos machine be sure to use Format /U. Unconditional format. The new format saves restoration info by default to the disk. It messes with Dos for some reason. Format /U eliminates this and will allow the disk to work in dos.

These solutions work 100% of the time for me. If they don't for you then it must be some configuration issue. What irks me is Micorsoft has no clue about these extremely simple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Run chkdsk /r command for that drive.

Please open the Disk Management and check if a drive letter is assigned to the floppy drive. Please follow these steps:

1. Press “Windows Logo” + “X” keys on the keyboard and select “Disk Management” from that list.
2. You should be able to see the hard disk partitions and the removable drives connected to the computer in the Disk Management.
3. Check if you have any drives without any drive letters assigned to it.
4. If you have floppy drive listed there without a drive letter, then you may assign the drive letter (A) to it and check if that is shown in “This PC”  now and then try to access it from the “Windows Explorer”.

If it persists, try to uninstall and Reinstall the Floppy Disk Drivers from the Device Manager:

1. Press “Windows Logo” + “X” keys on the keyboard.
2. Click on “Device Manager” from that list.
3. Search for the Floppy Disk device from the device list, right click on it and then select “Uninstall”. On the un-installation window, if you have an option: “Delete the driver software for this device” you may select that and then remove the corrupted drivers from the computer.
4. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete it and the restart the computer if prompted.
5. While the computer is shutting down, you may unplug the device and then re-plug the device once the WindowS is loaded on the computer.
6. Again go to “Device Manager” and then click on the “Scan for hardware changes” button.
7. Check if Windows detects the Floppy Disk device and installs an appropriate driver automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I found this from Microsoft support:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/140060/floppy-disk-is-not-accessible-not-formatted-or-not-recognized-by-windo

Evidently the problem is that newer versions of Windows require a different formatting of discs than older versions of Windows:

"This problem occurs on disks that do not contain a media descriptor byte in the BIOS parameter block (BPB) of the boot sector"

They list two ways to fix it.

> 1: "To resolve this problem, re-format the floppy disk with Windows
> 98, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP,
> or Windows Server 2003."
>
> 2: "Warning: This workaround is for advanced users only. This
> workaround involves using a disk sector editor to modify the media
> descriptor byte on the floppy disk."

So yeah. I'm trying to see if I can get some emulator or something that can read it, or get it open in DOS or something.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Pro here
Floppy wasn't showing up in Explorer and a Yellow triangle next to it in device manager.

The answer is not the Boot sector on my disks. Searched all over for the diskprobe and finally found on Major Geeks. Checked 10 floppies with DiskProbe I formatted with Virtual Box XP Mode and they all had the F0 for 1.44mb. BTW you can find the one for XP at Major Geeks "windowsxp-kb838079-supporttools-enu.exe"

Go Here
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/floppy-disk-drive-and-windows-10/26103611-d526-43e1-be09-78daf981b78b

Scroll down and find
Micheal Morris 2  post.
You  go to device manager then right click and select Update Driver, Browse my computer for driver software, Let me pick from a list, click on “Show All Devices” I got this
[Floppy drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cGE1.png)

Install, Reboot done deal. Chased this for a week in spare time cause it was working then it wasn't.